# How can I change color of a label when a combobox/textbox is highlighted in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to highlight/change the color of a label when a user is about to enter a text on an input box or select an item on a combobox. 
I have tried doing this:

```
if combobox1.Focus() then
     label.Forecolor = Color.White
End if
```

I thought it would be that simple but it didn't work.
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate events. Be aware that ForeColor only changes the color of the text in the label.

```
 Private Sub cboSheets_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboSheets.Enter
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.White
 End Sub

 Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.White
 End Sub
```

Comment: As Mary suggested, `ForeColor` only changes the text of the Label, you might want to consider using `BackColor` instead. One more thing, you might want to use the `Leave` event to "reset" the color to its original state when the TextBox/ComboBox loses focus.